# XML vs HTML? Scrapy downloads html files but not xml files?

Tags: python, html, xml, scrapy

EDIT: This is only scraping the XML links from the crawled pages, not actually following the links to the XML pages themselves, which have a slightly different URL.  I need to adjust the rules so I can crawl those pages as well.  I'll post a solution once I've got it working.

`http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/12/4/000401/000401.xml`
vs.
`http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/12/4/000401.xml`

This script scrapes all the links, and should save all the files, but only the html files are actually saved.  The xml files are added to the csv but not downloaded.  This is a relatively simple script so what is the difference between the two?

Here's the error I'm getting.

```
2022-12-22 12:33:30 [scrapy.pipelines.files] WARNING: File (code: 302): Error downloading file from <GET http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/12/4/000407.xml> referred in <None>
2022-12-22 12:33:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/12/4/000408.xml> (referer: None)
2022-12-22 12:33:30 [scrapy.pipelines.files] WARNING: File (code: 302): Error downloading file from <GET http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/12/4/000408.xml> referred in <None>
```

And example of the output:  https://pastebin.com/pDHvYTxF

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class DhqSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'dhqfiles'
    allowed_domains = ['digitalhumanities.org']
    start_urls = ['http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/16/3/index.html']

    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = 'index.html')), 
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = 'vol'), callback='parse_article'),        
        )

    def parse_article(self, response):
        article = { 
            'xmllink' : response.urljoin(response.xpath('(//div[@class="toolbar"]/a[contains(@href, ".xml")]/@href)[1]').get()),
        }
        yield {'file_urls':[article['xmllink']]}
```

Comment: because you are not yielding a space for the results....